# Is there any way for my App to get the list of bookmarks from the Apple Maps app?

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location, apple-maps

The Apple Maps app in iOS (or Mac OS X Mavericks) can have a list of bookmarks that can sync through iCloud.

Is there a way for an app that I am developing to get that list of bookmarks (NSArray of CLLocations)?

I'm working on an app that will create a Home region and a Work region. I understand how to create regions in my app, but for user convenience I was looking for a way for my app to query the Maps app and see if there any bookmarks labeled Home or Work. I haven't found it yet in "About Location Services and Maps" guide.

Comment: Great Question! I tried to find a way every once in a while but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible and Apple won't allow fetching such information in future as well. That information is private to Maps app.